# The condition of multivariable Taylor expansion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Multivariable Taylor expansion theory is:

> Given open set $D \in \mathbb{R}^n$ $ (n \geq 2)$ , $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb R^p, (p \geq 1)$  and $f \in C^k(D)$. Let $x \in D, u\in \mathbb{R}^n, u=(u_1,...,u_n)$ such that $ x+tu \in D, \forall t \in [0,1]$, then exits  $\theta \in [0,1]$ :
>   $$f(x+u)=f(x)+f'(x)(u)+...+\frac{1}{(k-1)!}f^{(k-1)}(x)(u)^{k-1}+\frac{1}{k!}f^{(k)}(x+\theta u)(u)^{k}\quad (1)$$
>   $$\lim_{u\rightarrow 0} \phi (u)=\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}{\frac{1}{k!}[f^{(k)}(x+\theta u)(u)^{k}-f^{(k)}(x)]}=0 \quad (2) $$

I can't understand why we must have the condition  $f^{(k)}$ is continuos on D  ($f \in C^k(D)$) instead of having $f$ is $k^{th}$-differential, because we just need to calculate $f^{(k)}(x), f^{(k)}(x+ \theta u)$ in (1)?

If now we assume that $f \in C^{k-1} (D) $ and f is $k^{th}$-differential in $D$,
I think that (1) is still right, but (2) is not. Is it right? I'm try to find an example to illustrate the point, but it's quite hard for me.

Comment: What is $h$ in the above?

Comment: Sorry, it is $u$, I've edited.

Comment: The continuity is to ensure uniformity over directions.

Comment: @copper.hat can you explain more about that?